# is there any way to get to know about database updates without querying /less queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I ran into a weird problem looking for the best solution that i can get here. I'm developing a rails application which displays data from a common database that is being used by another application(nodejs). All CRUD operations happens at the other platform. In the rails app, we just query and display the data.

In rails app, I need to auto update views without refreshing. for example

```
def index
    @states = State.page(params[:state_page])
    @level_one_companies = Company.includes(:state)
                                  .where(level: 1)
                                  .order('created_at DESC').limit(20)

    @level_two_companies = Company.includes(:state)
                                  .where(level: 2)
                                  .order('created_at DESC').limit(20)
end
```

On the index page i will have tables for each of these and I need to refresh tables when new data is added to the state, (or) Level 1 (or) Level 2 companies.

I know i can go with two ways to auto update views i.e

1. Action Cable.
2. Data pooling at a time interval using Jquery.

Usually while using Action Cable we will broadcast data from server after a record is created in the db(after .save in create action (or) after_save callback from model). However, I'm not creating any records through rails app.

My first question is, is there any way use action cable in this case?.

So i went with the second option and it's working fine. But it making too many db calls after every X seconds.
is there any way to reduce queries to update views?
What is the best way i can go with here? Any help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if your tags are set correctly, you are using postgres as a database.

postgres offers a publish-subscribe machanism that you could use in combination with action-cable in order to listen to changes in your database.

in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tayeke/6442390), you can find an example for postgres-pubsub with server-sent-events. it should be simple to translate this into action-cable compatible code.

Comment: Thank you @phoet, will give a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger on a table (creates/updates/deletes) that fires a notification on a "channel", and you can listen to said channel for events. I use socketcluster, listen from workers and broadcast to consumers (browsers and mobile apps).

First you create the trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION deletes_notify_trigger() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('deletes_channel',  ('DELETED' || ';;' || OLD.id )::text );
  RETURN new;
END;
$$;
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER deletes_trigger AFTER DELETE ON events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE deletes_notify_trigger();
```

You can add any stuff you want in the data packets being broadcast, in my case I just need the ID of the record. For creates and updates you could send the full row or only some selected columns. You can also send it as JSON in PG 9.2 (I think) and higher. I use 9.1 so I concat with ;; separators.

Make sure your code takes at most 10% of the time between your queries otherwise if you do complex joins or updates or other operations you will notice significant drops in performance. You want this to be as simple and fast as possible, keep it down to basic operations and do any heavy-lifting on the application layer.

Then, the watcher and broadcasting to consumers (in my case node, socketcluster and the pg gem, in your case you can use JS, Python, Ruby, whatever you like)

```
var global_deletes = socket.subscribe('deletes_channel');
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client) {
      client.on('notification', function(dbmsg) {
        console.log(dbmsg.payload);
        var payload = dbmsg.payload.split(";;"); // you can use JSON instead

        if (payload[0] == "DELETED") { // when a DELETE is received...
            global_deletes.publish(dbmsg.payload);
            var tchannel = socket.subscribe('events-'+ payload[1]); // join the channel we want to broadcast
            setTimeout( () => tchannel.publish(dbmsg.payload), 50); // send the update to all consumers
            setTimeout( () => tchannel.unsubscribe(), 100);
        }
       );
    var query = client.query("LISTEN deletes_channel"); // turn on notifications from the server
});
```